# How add meta property="og:locale" content="?"

Tags: html, seo, meta, facebook-opengraph

I have seen several different articles, and I want to know, to be sure what is right,
How add meta `og:locale` example: `en_US or en-US`  Which is correct? or is the same?

on my website I have add it like this

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to their documentation here http://ogp.me/,

> og:locale - The locale these tags are marked up in. Of the format language_TERRITORY. Default is en_US.

The accepted format is en_US, so your meta property tag is in the correct format. If you want to add an alternative language, you can do so with

```
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES" />
```

As stated in their website.